# Creating a layout without a border that overlays the background layer

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to create something like this in the screenshot. It has a main layout that is the background and layout that overlays it. I am not sure how this is done.

My best guess would be an dialog fragment. Is this the right way to do something like this.

[image]

My attempt at using the dialog fragment doesn't give me the results I would like and this is as close as I can get.

[image]

This is my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context="com.chatt.fragments.AddMember">

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_highlight_off_white_36dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivBackground"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:src="@drawable/world"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:alpha="0.4"/>

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/civProfilePhoto"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/user3"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/ivBackground"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvMemberName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-light"
            android:text="Sarah"
            android:textSize="26sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_anchor="@+id/civProfilePhoto"
            app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginTop="40dp"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_300">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibLock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_black_36dp"/>

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ibAddMember"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="60dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_36dp"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

I have used the Coordinator Layout to anchor the profile picture on the background. However, that works fine. But the name covers some of the profile picture. The icons I download from google icon pack. The buttoms show a very dark background and should be transparent. The close icon in the top right corner doesn't have a transparent background either. The dialog covers the whole screen.

I inflate my DialogFragment like this:

```
   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        getDialog().getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(0));
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_member, container, false);
    }
```

Many thanks for any suggestions,

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a small example of a layout that recreate the UI of your screenshot using the `DialogFragment`:

[image: the result]

The layout `fragment_add_member.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/world"/>

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_highlight_off_white_36dp"/>

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/civProfilePhoto"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="185dp"
        android:src="@drawable/profile"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="240dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Mattia"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="320dp"
        android:background="@color/material_grey_300">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ibLock"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|start"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_lock_black_36dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ibAddMember"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|end"
            android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_person_add_black_36dp"/>

    </FrameLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

The `DialogFragment`:

```
public class AddMemberDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_TITLE, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_member, container);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks that was perfect.

Answer (score 9):

Two approach that you can choose.

**1. Use DialogFragment**
It will give you shadow automatically.

```
public class OverlayDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // This will give you shadow with borderless frame.
        setStyle(DialogFragment.STYLE_NO_FRAME, 0);
    }

    // your code. define layout xml, etc....

}
```

**2. Use overlayed Layout and background drawable for shadow**

Define two Layouts in root RelativeLayout and adjust width and height of overlayed one. And then apply 9-patch background drawable.

```
<RelativeLayout
 android:id="@+id/layoutRoot"
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- your base UI elements here -->

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/overlayLayout"
        android:layout_width="600dp"
        android:layout_height="800dp"
        android:background="@drawable/img_bg_mask"
        android:orientation="vertical">
    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

And *img_bg_mask.png* looks like as below. Below image shows rounded corner as an example, but you can make a 9-patch image that has rectangled shadow.

[image]